# UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad detect if it has comma "," or dot "."

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uikeyboard

How can I check if the UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad has a dot/comma? I need this to check how many dots/commas are entered so I can limit them to only 1. I know how to do this when I know that the UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad has the comma.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

NSCharacterSet *cs;
NSString *filtered;

NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

if ([textField.text rangeOfString:@","].location == NSNotFound) {

    cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:NUMBERSPERIOD] invertedSet];
    filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
 }


else {

    cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:NUMBERS] invertedSet];
    filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];     

    NSUInteger count = 0, length = [newString length];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length); 
    while(range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        range = [newString rangeOfString: @"," options:0 range:range];
        if(range.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, length - (range.location + range.length));
            count++; 
        }
    }        

    if (count < 2) {

        NSArray *sep = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        if([sep count]>=2)
        {
            NSString *sepStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sep objectAtIndex:1]];
            return !([sepStr length]>2);
        }

        return YES;

    }

    return NO;

}
}
```

Is there easy way to check if the keyboard has the "," or "."?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect the character on that key is governed by the current locale. I say I suspect because I have not tested this. If this is correct the following should allow you to determine whether a comma or period/decimal point is there:

```
NSString *symbol = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator];
```

Comment: note: since iOS 10 you can use [NSLocale currentLocale].decimalSeparator